# First PIC Program using PIC16F877A and its configuration bits for Internal clock?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplabx

I have a *PIC16F877A* and I wrote a program in *MPLAB X IDE* to blink a LED.

This is my program :

```
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 6000000
void main()
{
    TRISB7 = 0;
   while(1)
   {
         RB7=1;
      __delay_ms(1000);
          RB7=0;
       __delay_ms(1000);
   }
}
```

I compiled it successfully, but when I load the **hex** file in *PICKit2v2* , it show a warning as below :

[image]

And also when I tried to write that **hex** file on MCU, It show the below error :

[image]

So I reopened my project in *MPLAB X IDE V2.26* and tried to add configuration data to my code, using the wizard in *Windows --> PIC Memory view --> Configuration Bits*
But when I click it, I see this below window on the bottom of screen :

[image]

Question 1 : Why most of memory is equal to `3FFF` in the first and second image that I attached above? Does that mean my program is just about 6 byte? (The first six bytes are different)

Question 2 : The error that I received is about configuration bits? Or it is something else?!

Question 3 : Which one of this optioned must I select for internal clock? I don't want to use any external clock or crystal o RC.

Question 4 : What is the difference between **htc.h** and **xc.h** libraries? I some of example code in the internet I saw **htc.h** included in the above of program? What is it for? Which libraries is for *delay()* function?

Question 5 : Is the second line in my program mandatory (I mean `#define _XTAL_FREQ 6000000`) Does it for external crystal? or ...?

I am a brand new in PIC MCU's programming. Pleas shed any light on this issue for me and for future viewers.

---

**Update :**

I added configuration setting to my program :
Now this is my program :

```
/*
 * File:   newmain.c
 * Author: Amir Ebrahim
 *
 * Created on January 3, 2015, 1:42 PM
 */

#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 12000000

#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = ON        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)



void main()
{
    TRISB7 = 0;
   while(1)
   {
         RB7=1;
      __delay_ms(1000);
          RB7=0;
       __delay_ms(1000);
   }
}
```

When I load the **hex** file in *PICKit2v2* I received successful load :

[image]

But when I want to write the file on the MCU, I receive the same previous error!

[image]

Why?! :(

Comment: Have you tried flashing another PIC?

Comment: @Triak No, Unfortunately I have bought only one MCU! FYI, I can erase it and read it successfully. But I can't write to it! May the MCU was corrupted while I can read/erase it?

Comment: Well, then your programmer is fine... Get another PIC (ex.16F628A) and try to burn a 'HelloWorld' program. Your PIC might be dead... What programmer do you use ?

Comment: @Triak I don't know what kind of programmer I have!! On the box is written "PICKIT2- MOdel: PUP0401" and you can see two image of it here : http://eshop.eca.ir/1673-thickbox_default/pic-usb-programmer.jpg and http://eshop.eca.ir/1674-large_default/pic-usb-programmer.jpg

Successfully reading and erasing doesn't mean that my PIC is not dead?

Comment: Do you program the PIC through IC socket or ICSP ?

Comment: @Triak  don't know! I think I program it through an IC socket, Because I put it in a zif socket on my programmer board and the do flashing

Comment: Try programming another PIC...

Comment: I see that MPLABX v2.26 has 'beta' support for PICkit2 when I set up a dummy project for the PIC16F877A. Try programming it directly from MPLABX instead of with the standalone programming tool. Also, consider investing in a PICkit3 programmer - PICkit2 is largely obsolete these days.

Comment: @AdamLawrence Please take a look at my another question here : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146071/mplab-x-ide-problem-with-pic-programmer

Answer (score 5):

> Question 1 : Why most of memory is equal to 3FFF in the first and second image that I attached above? Does that mean my program is just about 6 byte? (The first six bytes are different)

Scroll down - you'll see more than just those. The first bit is "jump to your code", then there's the vector table for the interrupts, then there's your code.

> Question 2 : The error that I received is about configuration bits? Or it is something else?!

That's what it says, isn't it? Without config bits it won't work.

> Question 3 : Which one of this optioned must I select for internal clock? I don't want to use any external clock or crystal or RC.

The PIC16F877A has no internal oscillator. For that you want to pick a more modern chip.

> Question 4 : What is the difference between htc.h and xc.h libraries? I some of example code in the internet I saw htc.h included in the above of program? What is it for? Which libraries is for delay() function?

`htc.h` is for the Hi-Tec compiler. `xc.h` is for the XC8 compiler.  Pick the one for your compiler.

> Question 5 : Is the second line in my program mandatory (I mean #define _XTAL_FREQ 6000000) Does it for external crystal? or ...?

That may be used for the timing of `__delay_ms()` depending on your compiler's implementation.  If so, it needs to match the crystal you attach to the chip.

Comment: Would you please take a look at the **Update** section in the question? Thanks